# Warning when dynamically allocating memory

Tags: c++, c++11, warnings, compiler-warnings

I'm using dynamic allocation for the first time and the compiler gives me this warning which I couldn't find anywhere else:

```
warning: non-static data member initializers only available with 
-std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
```

Is there a way to make it desappear? Should I care?
Thanks!

Comment: Aside from warning, you need to post code which causes this.

Comment: What part of "-std=c++11" is unclear?

Comment: Yes, you should care about the warning.  And before blindly adding a flag to your compilation command to make the warning disappear, you should understand the nature of the problem your compiler is warning about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The problem:**

It has nothing to do with *dynamic allocation*.

You are probably using one of this methods for data member initialization which are part of C++11:

```
class S
{
    int n;                // non-static data member
    int& r;               // non-static data member of reference type
    int a[10] = {1, 2};   // non-static data member with initializer (C++11)
    std::string s, *ps;   // two non-static data members
    struct NestedS {
        std::string s;
    } d5, *d6;            // two non-static data members of nested type
    char bit : 2;         // two-bit bitfield
};
```

[Source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members)

The compiler tells you that you are using a feature (non-static data member initializers) that is only exist in C++11 (and above).

**Solving the problem:**

- You may simply compile your code with `-std=c++11` flag.
- Alternatively, you may avoid using this feature if you want to stick with older standard (e.g. C++98) for some reason (like you are targeting some system where no C++ 11 compiler is avaible).

> Should I care?

Absolutely, yes. No giving attention to warnings may leads to many problems like overflows and undefined behaviours.

Comment: I knew nothing about the -std=c++11 flag, I'll defenetely use it! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

*Always* care about warnings! Warnings are useful, in fact, you should always compile with `-Werror`.

It is warning you that you are compiling in pre-C++11, but are using C++11 in-class initializers in your code:

```
struct foo {
    int i = 0; // initialization of non-static POD
};
```

You'll have to compile with `-std=c++11`, or stop using that feature and initialize the data members in the constructor.